# How do I make GroupBox act like a container when dragging new controls into it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

GroupBox in Visual C++ doesn't behave like I expect. Dropping new items into the GroupBox does not "associate" the items with the GroupBox. Thus, if the GroupBox is repositioned (with designer), the items inside the GroupBox are not moved along with it.

Does the GroupBox control work differently in Visual C++ where the relation needs to be done in code, or is there a way to enable this? C# Forms designer performs this way, so does QT. Didn't expect this. Thanks

Comment: No relation needs to be done, in code or elsewhere. Group box control is purely cosmetic, it doesn't have any logical function. It's just there to draw a frame, nothing else.

Comment: Works fine, as it should.  The designer is not special for C++, it must work the same as it does in C# since the exact same code is used.  Only the design code serializer is different, producing C++/CLI code instead of C# code.  You left no cue to guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant So in C# you if drop buttons, labels or other control items into a groupBox they are able to to be moved as one entity around the form. But in Visual C++ (or at least for me) it's just acting like an outlined box without the ability to "group" anything in it. I guess it's not that big of a deal just easier to organize the contents inside the box and then be able to move the box around the form to adjust the layout without having to select everything.